# Adding too many plugins/extensions to a browser, affect browsing speed?

Tags: performance, plugins, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, pagespeed

I am using extensions added from the official websites like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/extensions/ , https://chrome.google.com/webstore.
If the answer is Yes, is there any way to find out which plugin causing trouble.

Question related to 'browsing speed': [Does browsing speed depend on the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432915/does-browsing-speed-depend-on-the-browser) is not talking about browser plugins

Comment: This is a question for http://superuser.com. The general method in such cases is disabling all extensions, enable them one by one and check if the issue is gone. You may also need to reset the flags on `chrome://flags` page.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm for pointing it out. Created a new question in superuser.com.

Answer (score 2):

If you believe the problem might be caused by any single specific extension, you disable/enable your extensions to find the culprit.  There is an add-on for Firefox that does this.  It's called *Extension Conflict Troubleshooter for Firefox* and can be found on [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/extension-conflict-troubleshoo/).